# Local Jenkins on windows connecting to remote GitLab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I want to create a webhook in remote gitlab via local jenkins installation. I managed to connect them and manually build project in gitlab after commits. But I want to do this automatically by webhook.
I got an error "Url is blocked: Requests to the local network are not allowed"
because I 'm setting webhook url in gitlab as http://172.25.203.193:9090/project/testJenkins_Angular. How could I skip this error?  172.25.203.193:9090 is Jenkin's domain. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be overridden by enabling the option “**Allow requests to the local network from hooks and services**” in the “Outbound requests” section inside the Admin area under Settings (**/admin/application_settings/network**)

Please follow [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/webhooks.html) for more information.

Comment: I can't  find this option in remote https://gitlab.com/ . I believe that this option "Admin area" is only for on-premise gitlab.